# Change properties of dynamically declared button

Tags: c#

I have a dynamically created button in c#. 
The code is basically like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Name = "dynabutt";
this.Controls.Add(b);
```

I want to have a non-dynamic button,button2, so that when I click button2,
the color of the dynamic button changes. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? This is not that hard to do, but I don't want to spell everything out for you if you haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: In the click event for `button2` you need to identify a reference to `b` and then set properties on that reference.  Maybe make `b` a class-level member or put it in some other shared location?  Maybe dynamically find `b` in a `Controls` collection on the form?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to attach an event handler to `Click` event of `Button2`.And if you know the name of *dynamic button* all you need to do is access it from your Controls collection and change it's color like this:

```
button2.Click += (s,e) => { this.Controls["dynabutt"].BackColor = Color.Blue; };
```

Comment: possible `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just declare variable b somewhere globally to be visible out of method (or assign to some other variable), for example:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Button button1 = null;
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = "dynabutt";
        this.Controls.Add(b);
        button1 = b;
        button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    public void button2_Click(...)
    {
        if (button1 != null) button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must check for NULL, if `button2_Click()` is executed before `SomeMethod()` you will get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that. :)